# How to save data to a specific uid for a specific logged in user in swift/firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to allow a user to save data to a tableView using an alert that transfer data from the View Controller that the alert is in (CreatePlaylistVC) to another ViewController(CreatedPlaylistVC) that the tableView is in, saving for each specific account for a specific uid.

I've tried setting the value to the uid but this did work for me although it did save to the database under that specific uid.

**CreatePlaylistVC**

```
ref = Database.database().reference()

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style:.default, handler: {
action in



    if let playlistName = alert.textFields?.first?.text {


        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        self.ref?.child("PlaylistName").child(userID!).setValue(playlistName)
```

**CreatedPlaylistVC**

```
var ref:DatabaseReference?
var databaseHandle:DatabaseHandle?

override func viewDidLoad() {


    //Set the firebase reference
    ref = Database.database().reference()

  //Retrieve the posts and listen fro changes
    databaseHandle = ref?.child("PlaylistName").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in


      //Try to covert the value of the data to a string
        let post = snapshot.value as? String

        if let actualPost = post {

           //Append the data to our playlistNameArray
            self.playlistNameArray.append(actualPost)

            //Reload the tableView
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

The expected results is to save the data only for the specified uid or currently logged in user. But it is saving for each user even though in the database it is saved to the right uid.

Answer (score 0):

When using .childAdded for observe, it will go through every existing child under "PlaylistName" which in this case will be every user that has saved something.

Might have to reconsider your structure. Or use childByAutoID.

Edit: To use child by auto ID

```
// Your ["Name": Playlist] will get nested into an autogenerated child
self.ref?.child("PlaylistName").child(userID!).childByAutoID().setValue(["Name":playlistName])
```

```
//You will be listening for any new additions that your current user has made
databaseHandle = ref?.child("PlaylistName").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        // this loops through a list of playlist names your user creates
        for child in snapshot.children{

            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let value = snap.value as? Dict<String,Any>
            let post = value["Name"] as! String

            if let actualPost = post {

                self.playlistNameArray.append(actualPost)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
```

But my suggestion, if it suits your application, would be to change your data structure because it can keep your structure a lot flatter.

```
self.ref?.child(userID!).child("PlaylistName").setValue(playListName)
```

```
databaseHandle = ref?.child(userID!).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? Dict<String,Any>
        let post = value["PlaylistName"]

        if let actualPost = post {

            self.playlistNameArray.append(actualPost)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
```

Comment: I've edited my answer to answer your question. Let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: I've got it to work by using the parts of your code. Thank you!